# Excel index + match with multiple criteria and a particular use of the match mode

Tags: excel-formula, match

I'm trying to combine Excel formulas `index` and `match` with multiple criteria, where one of the criteria is an approximate match.

Unlike columns 1 and 2, where I'm looking for an exact match, the match mode argument of the match function - "exact match or next large item" - is needed for the criteria in Column 3.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

**Match criteria:** A, Y, 185

**Expected return:** 55.88

I think this is an interesting problem. Will accept answers that don't use index + match as well.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I got this done by using `XMATCH`, which isn't available in older versions of Excel: `=INDEX(Table1[Column 4],XMATCH(185,(Table1[Column 1]="A")*(Table1[Column 2]="Y")*(Table1[Column 3]),1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XLOOKUP is a powerful new function.
The first 1 is referring to the first result.

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(A2:A17="A")*(B2:B17="Y")*(C2:C17>185),D2:D17)
```